# Searching not working in ajax once textbox onblur event is called

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code to search through AJAX. Now if I apply `onblur` event to the textbox (so that searching result disappears) and get back to the textbox again, searching facility is no more working. So the thing is, it might not be able to call `onfocus` event properly once `onblur` event is called. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".searchproductbrand").keyup(function () {
        var kw = $(".searchproductbrand").val();
        if (kw != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "livesearch.php",
            data: "kw=" + kw,
            success: function (option) {
                $("#livesearch").html(option);
                document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "1px solid #A5ACB2";
            }
        });
        } else {
            $("#livesearch").html("");
            document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "0px";
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".searchproductbrand").blur(function () {
        document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display = "none";
    })
});
</script>
```

Livesearch is the `div` where I print my search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your livesearch is still hidden, try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".searchproductbrand").keyup(function () {
        var kw = $(".searchproductbrand").val();
        if (kw != '') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "livesearch.php",
            data: "kw=" + kw,
            success: function (option) {
                $("#livesearch").show(); // this is
                $("#livesearch").html(option);
                document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "1px solid #A5ACB2";
            }
        });
        } else {
            $("#livesearch").html("");
            document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border = "0px";
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".searchproductbrand").blur(function () {
        document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display = "none";
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: That's exactly I was missing. Thanks a ton, worked perfectly.:)

Answer (score 2):

You should provide your markup, or a jsfiddle but i'm almost sure that everything is working but on the onblur event you set the display rule of the 'livesearch' element  to none, but you never set it back to block so you made it invisible and it stayed that way because you need to set it to block or whatever visibible display rule that you want, i created a jsfiddle example based on what you posted, i took the liberty to alter your code and removed the ajax part so you can focus on the real issue, i hope this solves your problem.

[http://jsfiddle.net/kFj9u/1](http://jsfiddle.net/kFj9u/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $liveSearch = $('#liveSearch');
    $(".searchProductBrand").keyup(function(){
    var keyWord = $(this).val();
    if(keyWord != ''){
        var msg = 'You searched for ' + keyWord;
        $liveSearch.css('display','block').html(msg);
    }else{
       $liveSearch.html('').
       css('border','none');

    }

   }).blur(function(){
    $liveSearch.css('display','none');
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's something I was missing. Worked fine after that:)